# Fedora27 on lenovo yoga 920

Tags: linux, fedora

I have a Lenovo yoga 920 with a fresh installed Fedora. I configured already the Wifi to make it work and some smaller problems. But I have two problems:

Fingerprint It seems the fingerprint cant be detected so I cant use it. As far as I found out there a no official drivers or anything

Touch + Autorotate Does Fedora not support autorotation? I did not find any drivers or settings if I want to use the laptop in tablet mode (the keyboard is disabled correct)

Further, I have one question, I could configure the active pen which is delivered together with the Lenovo 920, but is there any tool for using the active pen to write on the screen (so not only the screen keyboard, more a tool to detect my handwriting)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint reader uses some secure connection which is not supported in Linux as far as I know.  It may never be supported.

Fedora doesn't have autorotate built in directly.   There may be something in Gnome that does it.  I hacked together an autorotate system for the Yoga 2 Pro quite some time ago but haven't been using autorotate for a few years and haven't installed it on my 920 (running Fedora 27 XFCE).

I set up the active pen early on.  Gimp treats it as an airbrush and uses its pressure sensitivity.

See https://linlap.info/lenovo_yoga_920 for more information.